# Change userAgent in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, user-agent, user-agent-switcher

I am trying to change userAgent for my Flutter Web app as it adapts to different phone sizes but not desktop. To tackle this problem, I want to change the userAgent on desktop devices to show a phone/tablet screen size. How can I do this?